# Почему у меня не отображается надпись "Hello World " на экране слева и справа в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Начал изучать создание андроид приложений, смотрю уроки на ютубе. И на видео показано, как у человека отображается текст "hello world "на этих двух экранах,а у меня нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может код надо показать?)

Comment: не этот...xml..

Comment: нажми на восклицательный знак с красном кружке и покажи ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открой файл styles и найди строку с theme и удали последнее слово до точки и вместо него напиши NoActionBar. И обнови экран

Вот пример

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

Или нажми на AppTheme рядом с цифрой 28. Откроется окно, там тоже можно поменять на NoActionBar

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Спасибо, мне тоже помогло. А что значит эта строка ?

Comment: Отключает  в теме ActionBar( такая полоска сверху приложения, на которой можно расположить элементы). Почему то сейчас есть такой баг с белым экраном. Но если нужен actionbar, то его можно отключить в теме, а потом добавить в свой layout AppBarLayout и он тогда останется, но без бага