# Не отображаются пункты ListView в визуальном редакторе

Tags: android, android-studio

В визуальном редакторе не отображаются пункты ListView. Лишь только:
**Item 1
Sub Item 1;
Item 2
Sub Item 2;
Item 3
Sub Item 3**
и т.д. до конца экрана.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Используется LinearLayout в вертикальной ориентации. А два ListView не располагаются один над другим, а один над другим (это только в визуальном редакторе. В данном случае меня интересует виз. редактор).

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_options1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/options1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_options2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/options2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Простейшее</string>
    <string-array name="options1">
        <item>Пункт_1</item>
        <item>Пункт_2</item>
        <item>Пункт_3</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="options2">
        <item>Пункт_4</item>
        <item>Пункт_5</item>
        <item>Пункт_6</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Ну и **MainActivity**, который создала студия.

Попробовал разместить два ListView не один под другим, а рядом друг с другом с горизонтальной ориентацией LinearLayout ну, и, конечно, поменял *android:layout_width, android:layout_height* на *wrap_content*. Результат такой же, как и в первом случае - на весь экран только **Item 1
Sub Item 1;
Item 2
Sub Item 2;
Item 3
Sub Item 3** и т.д.
Только начинаю разбираться. Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Пункты списка и не должны отображаться в визуальном редакторе. То, что вы видите - это всего лишь превью (картинка с положением виджетов на экране), а не полноценный эмулятор. Ведь для того, чтобы заполнить айтем данными, должен выполняться код, а это возможно только в эмуляторе или реальном устройстве, соответственно, чтобы увидеть действительный вид своего приложения, вам нужно [запустить вашу программу на выполнение](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/) (зеленый треугольник в панели инструментов).

Если вам все же важно видеть ваши айтемы именно на превью, вы можете потратить дополнительное время, на бессмысленное, в общем то украшение и воспользоваться возможностостями [пространства имен `tools`](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes) XML-разметки. В частности `tools:listitem`, который нарисует вам желанный айтем, но тоже с ограничениями, например, он будет заполнен шаблонными, а не актуальными данными. Вы можете решить и эту проблему через атрибут `tools:sample`, который будет подставлять заранее подготовленные данные.

[Пример работы со списком](https://android.jlelse.eu/tools-attributes-hidden-gems-of-android-studio-d7451b194e0b) через инструмент tools. Напомню, что и в этом случае вы не увидите то, что будет на самом деле при работе вашей программы. Просто будут подставлены какие то данные, которые вы заранее **отдельно** подготовите **специально** для этих целей.

Вопрос в том, нужно ли все это .. В любом случае превью дает лишь примерное представление о том, что будет на экране - это не исполняемый код, а рендер и на то, что он показывает полагаться не стоит (иначе вас ждут сюрпризы при запуске на устройстве). Для полноценного представления о том, что получилось и как будет выглядеть на экране нужно тестировать только [на эмуляторе](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator) или реальном устройстве.

PS: для того, чтобы подобные нюансы не ставили вас в тупик, рекомендую читать литературу, где комплексно (в одном месте) рассказывается обо всех нюансах android-разработки. Например, замечательную книгу *Б.Филлипс "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" 3-е издание 2017 г.* В этой книге уделяется много внимания не только самой разработке, но и таким вещам, как работа с IDE Android Studio и читая ее у вас бы точно не появилось проблемы, как в вопросе.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый объект. Все ясно. В таком случае, как я понимаю,  теряется полный смысл в части Android Studio как визуальный редактор. Ведь я даже примерно не вижу той компоновки на экране. И, более того, редактор даже вводит в заблуждение. Если, например, я пожелаю поставить какой-либо ImageView между двумя ListView, то тоже ничего не увижу. Я не говорю про мои какие-то данные из массива, но даже не выдерживаются размеры. Компоненты просто не рисуются. 
P.S. За книгу спасибо. Уже скачал. Буду изучать.

Comment: Вы можете увидеть компоновку айтема, открыв в визуальном редакторе разметку самого айтема (вы увидите, как выглядит один элемент), в том числе и из ресурсов API Android. Так же на разметке безусловно отображаются и "какие-либо" ImageView между двумя ListView и размеры выдерживаются, по крайней мере для указанных в визуальном редакторе параметров экрана - визуальный редактор не настолько плох :) Возможно проблемы с вашей версткой.

Comment: Чтобы выдерживались размеры на всем многообразии android-устройств, нужно [использовать адаптивную верстку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483756/177345), а не хардкорные значения для размеров виджетов. Так же в недавних пор существует проблема "глюков" в визуальном редакторе (на превью не отображается вообще ничего), однозначного решения которой пока не найдено и нужно ждать исправления (кому то помогает [изменение темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/869166/177345), кому то [изменение API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/857293/177345)), возможно у вас та же проблема.

Comment: Если ответ помог вам решить проблему, прочитайте ,что здесь нужно делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос и как сказать здесь "спасибо"